# SQL Unique Constraint on Subset of data in table

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint, unique-key

I have a SQL Server table tbl_Submissions which contains a number of records for any given CaseID. Each Submission has an AuthorisedStatus field which can be "Authorised", "Rejected", "Rescinded". There could be multiple rejected or rescinded submissions for a CaseID, but there can only ever be one authorised record.

Is it possible to add a constraint or index to enforce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be implemeneted using [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX udx ON tbl_Sumbissions(CaseID)
WHERE AuthorisedStatus = 'Authorised'
```